# Dimension too large with tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree, linguistics

I want to draw a tree with tikz-qtree, but it bails with `Dimension
too large`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\Tree [.CP [.TP [.NP [ ] [.N' [ ] [.N Abelard ] ] ] [.T has ] [.V' [.V written ] [.NP [.D a ] [.N volume ] [.PP [.P' [.P of ] [.NP [ ] [.N' [.N poems ] [ ] ] ] ] ] ] [.PP [.P' [.P in [.NP [ ] [.N' [.N Latin ] [ ] ] ] ] ] ] [.PP [.P' [.P for ] [.NP [ ] [.N' [.N Héloïse ] [ ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As percusse has noted (answer now deleted) the problem is with completely empty nodes.  Filling them with a space element such as `\,` would add an empty terminal node, which would remove the error, but also yields extra vertical branches in the tree, which is not really what you probably want. A better solution is to add empty node *labels* instead of using spaces as terminal nodes:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\Tree [.CP [.TP 
       [.NP [.{} ] [.N' [.N Abelard ] ] ] 
       [.T has ] 
       [.V' [.V written ] 
            [.NP [.D a ] 
                 [.N volume ] 
                 [.PP [.P' [.P of ] 
                      [.NP [.{} ] 
                      [.N' [.N poems ] [.{} ] ] ] ] ] ] 
            [.PP [.P' [.P in [.NP [.{} ] 
                      [.N' [.N Latin ] 
                      [.{} ] ] ] ] ] ] 
            [.PP [.P' [.P for ] 
                      [.NP [.{} ] 
                      [.N' [.N Heloise ] 
                      [.{} ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Personally, as a linguist, I would just leave the empty nodes out of the tree altogether:

(code omitted)

[image: second output]

Comment: It was good enough, but yours @AlanMunn looks clearly better. Well, we were instructed to draw empty branches in this one exercise.